# Is it bad smell when mocking objects in multiple hierarchical dependencies?

Tags: java, unit-testing

Don't know if it is clear. But what I really want to statement is when I am trying to do the unit test in java, I find that I have to mock a lot of dependencies on a lot of services, and much more badly is that I cannot do the mock on some inter-invocation between methods, because  my mock parameters aren't equals with the object parameters created by the caller in the service.

In my opinion, this may be some smell versus test-friendly design.

Anyone has good advice on this topic? 
Thanks

Comment: Have to admit that this situation may most happen when there is a lot dependencies on third parties or other services in my own case. Or when there are some private methods invoked in the logic we want to test.

Answer (score 2):

Having multiple dependencies to stub is a bad small and give us information that design is not optimal. But you can decrease count of mock/stub statement with `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` option in mockito. 
Example:
http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.3/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS

Comment: Thanks, it is ok for void arguments, but if the method we want to mock has any input argument. How to fit that kind of mock?

Comment: The example in mockito for RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS means a lot, but the hard thing I want to demonstrate is that the logic tested has some mocked services and using input arguments created by the logic, but I created the mock service and do the mock to the method with my stub input arguments, according to the mechanism of easymock or mockito, this mocked stub input arguments wouldn't work as the argument created  by the logic.